# Python Loop not finishing

Tags: python

I made a script for organizing torrents. I download tv shows and then move files to another disk to a folder like /series name/season xx/
It was working with some issues until I've added a couple of ifs. I saw the problem of case sensitivity. For example, If i download mr robot.mkv and the folder Mr Robot already existed it created a different folder as mr robot. I did the same with season not to double move Season if season already exists.
Apparently my script is trying to create the folder continuosly and I don't see why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, glob, re, os, shutil
from termcolor import colored
#enconding: utf-8

dir_series = "/home/user/series/series/"

buscar = "*[sS][0-9][0-9]*"

series = [s for s in glob.glob(buscar) if s.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv'))]
if series:
    arch_encontrados = len(series)
    print(colored("\nArchivos encontrados:",'red', attrs=['bold'] ), colored(arch_encontrados, 'red', attrs=['bold'] ),'\n')
    print(*series, sep = "\n")

    for serie in series:

        #Extraer el nombre de la serie
        nombre = re.findall(r'.*[\. ][sS]\d', serie)[0]
        nombre_final = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]\d','',nombre).replace('.',' ')
        #Extraer el número de la temporada
        season = re.findall(r'[\. ][sS]\d\d', serie)[0]
        season_final_numero = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]','',season)
        season_final = ('Season ' + season_final_numero)
        #Armar el directorio final
        for series_path in os.listdir(dir_series): #lista el contenido de /home/user/series/series/
          if nombre_final.lower() == series_path.lower(): #compara el listado con la salida del nombre de la serie sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas
              for season_path in os.listdir(dir_series + series_path):
               if season_final == season_path: #compara el listado de seasons contra season_final que tiene mayuscula
                path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, season_final)
                print(path)
               else:
                path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, 'season ', season_final_numero)
          else:
           print(colored("\n\n*****************************************",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
           print(colored("** Directorio no encontrado, creándolo **",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
           print(colored("*****************************************\n",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
           path = os.path.join(dir_series, nombre_final, season_final)
           print(path)
           os.makedirs(path) 

        #Mover el archivo
        print(colored('\nCopiando','green'), serie, colored('a', 'green'), path + '/' + serie)
        shutil.move(serie,path)



else:
    print(colored('\nNo hay archivos para organizar.','green', attrs=['bold']))

input(colored("\n\nPresione Enter para continuar ...", attrs=['blink', 'bold']))
```

Comment: I think it would help others debug your problem if you could simplify your code to be a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is, there is too much code here for someone to easily look through.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing an infinite loop, but I think I do see a bug that is causing the same directory to get made many times.

You are calling `os.makedirs` in the else of your inner for loop, which means that you will make the same directory once for each file in `os.listdir(dir_series)` that does NOT match `nombre_final.lower()`.

I think the issue might just be that you (or your IDE) accidentally indented the `os.makedirs(path)` call two levels too deep when you added the if/else. I think it needs to be outside of the inner loop entirely.

You probably also need to add a `break` in the case where it does match, and maybe also a guard to stop it from making a new directory in the case where a match was found?